# How to print specific lines of a text file with cut

Tags: linux, text-processing, grep, cut

I have the next fragment of the output of a log:

```
Server Server: Server
Date and Time: June 04 2018 14:10:00
--

Product     Version         User         Host             IP             Duration

Software1      11.0     user               user         *.**.***.***     10:08
Software2      11.0      user                user        *.**.***.***     10:05
===================================================================================
```

I want with *cut* command only filter to the output like:

```
Product     Version         Host             IP             Duration

Software1      11.0    user             *.**.***.***     10:08
Software2      11.0     user            *.**.***.***     10:05
```

Also, I want to know if is possible apply the same filter many times, because the first example above, it repeats himself in the whole file.

Comment: The `cut` command selects columns (fields) to retain, but it does not help with filtering lines. From the example it appears the goal is to do both. It is not clear from the example if lines can be filtered strictly by pattern matching (eg. `grep`), but that's a possibility. Or it might be necessary to use an `awk` script or some other scripting language. It's not really clear from the sample fragments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using awk:

```
 awk '/--/{flag=1; next} /====/{flag=0} flag' filename
```

Using SED:

```
 sed -n '/--/,/===/{/--/!{/===/!p}}' filename
```

Using grep:

```
grep -E 'Product|Mathematica|MathKernel|Syntax' filename
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't really use `cut` in this case as the columns of the data are not clearly defined.  The `cut` utility works by cutting at exact numbers, e.g. exactly at 3 spaces or tabs or whatever delimiter you have. In this case, you will need to use `awk` which splits its input lines on any number of consecutive whitespaces (by default).

```
$ awk -v OFS="\t" '/^==/ { next } NR > 4 { print $1, $2, $4, $5, $6 }' file | column -t
Product    Version  Host  IP            Duration
Software1  11.0     user  *.**.***.***  10:08
Software2  11.0     user  *.**.***.***  10:05
```

The `awk` program skips any line starting with `==` and any line before the 5th line. For all other lines, it prints a selection of the fields (not the 3rd, `User`).

The `column -t` at the end formats the result into a nice table.

Comment: Can you support to me answering this question? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/461593/count-every-string-of-awk-output-search-in-a-file/461627?noredirect=1#comment839823_461627

Comment: By the way, cool format with column -t, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found the simplest solution to this:

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$4,$5,$6}' file1.log > file2.log
```

This allows only print my preferred columns

```
Product     Version         Host             IP             Duration

Software1       11.0         User          *.**.***.***     10:08
Software2        11.0        User           *.**.***.***     10:05
```

I didn't realize the important use of `awk`

Comment: This is different from the expected output in the question. It furthermore does not produce that output for the data in the question.

Comment: The `awk` code is also faulty (the parentheses should be curly braces).

Comment: Mmm I don't think so @Kusalananda, because I had not knowledge about awk, if objective case I accomplished the objective: Give a specific Output.
But I'll try to be more specific with alternatives in a future; Thank you for your interest